# How do I use joinWith to join more than 2 datasets?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I want to achieve something like this:

```
x.joinWith(y, x(id) === y(fid), "left_outer")
  .joinWith(z, x(id) === z(fid))
  .map(case {(x, y, z) => combineXYZ(x, y, z)})
```

Comment: What have you tried ? Any example datasets for input / output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `joinWith`, What you get is a new Dataset of Tuple2 : `(x, y)`. So the column names are `_1` and `_2`.

So when you do your second join, you need to reference a column name from the tuple, not from one of the source dataset. Like that :

```scala
x.joinWith(y, x(id) === y(fid), "left_outer").joinWith(z, $"_1.id" === z(fid))
```

Now, what you get is a tuple2 where first element is also a tuple : `((x, y), z)`. So you must do your map like :

```scala
.map(case {((x, y), z) => combineXYZ(x, y, z)})
```

This should work. Note that If you don't want to use `$"_1.id`, which is totally understandable, you can do a map after your first join, in order to create a new object, other than a tuple2, in order to get the correct column name.