Joining two nested columns of spark scala datasets
In spark scala, I am attempting to use join on two nested columns from two datasets. Spark seems to fail to join correctly (return rows not matching the join condition) :
case class A(id: String)
case class B(randomField: String)

val ds1 = spark.createDataset(Seq(A("5"), A("4")))
val ds2 = spark.createDataset(Seq(B("4"), B("5")))
val ds3 = ds1.joinWith(ds2, ds1("id") === ds2("randomField"))
ds3.show
/*
+---+---+
| _1| _2|
+---+---+
|{5}|{5}|
|{4}|{4}|
+---+---+
*/


ds3
.joinWith(
    ds3,
    ds3("_1.id") === ds3("_1.id"),
    "inner"
)

/*
Result :
+----------+----------+
|        _1|        _2|
+----------+----------+
|{{5}, {5}}|{{5}, {5}}|
|{{5}, {5}}|{{4}, {4}}|
|{{4}, {4}}|{{5}, {5}}|
|{{4}, {4}}|{{4}, {4}}|
+----------+----------+

Expected :
+----------+----------+
|        _1|        _2|
+----------+----------+
|{{5}, {5}}|{{5}, {5}}|
|{{4}, {4}}|{{4}, {4}}|
+----------+----------+
*/

What am I missing ? Is spark behaving weirdly when dealing with nested columns ? I get the correct result when extracting the column to the root level :
ds3.withColumn("id1", col("_1.id"))
.joinWith(
    ds3.withColumn("id2", col("_1.id")),
    col("id1") === col("id2"),
    "inner"
)

/*
Result :
+-------------+-------------+
|           _1|           _2|
+-------------+-------------+
|{{5}, {5}, 5}|{{5}, {5}, 5}|
|{{4}, {4}, 4}|{{4}, {4}, 4}|
+-------------+-------------+
*/


Refer to this answer for more details.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57474025/3238085
Use an editor like Intellij IDEA Community for better type information.
This works.
val sparkConfig = new SparkConf()
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Example")
  .config(sparkConfig)
  .getOrCreate()



import spark.implicits._
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")


val ds1 = spark.createDataset(Seq(A("5"), A("4")))
val ds2 = spark.createDataset(Seq(B("4"), B("5")))
val ds3 = ds1.joinWith(ds2, ds1("id") === ds2("randomField"))

ds3.show(20, truncate = false)


val ds4 = ds3.alias("first")
  .joinWith(
    ds3.alias("second"),
    col("first._1") === col("second._1") && col("first._2") === col("second._2"),
    "inner"
  )

ds4.show(20, truncate = false)

Output :
+---+---+
|_1 |_2 |
+---+---+
|{5}|{5}|
|{4}|{4}|
+---+---+

+----------+----------+
|_1        |_2        |
+----------+----------+
|{{5}, {5}}|{{5}, {5}}|
|{{4}, {4}}|{{4}, {4}}|
+----------+----------+

